Response 302 Found and the javascript file is not loaded
I created a custom handler to redirect the requests for a js file, thus this method checks if the requests are authenticated before the file is returned. It works perfectly fine on my local machine but it returns a 302 Found on stage and the js file is not loaded, looking at logs I noticed there is no error
web.config
   <add name="HandlerForMyJsfile" verb="*"
             path="Scripts/MyJsFile.js"
             type="Namespace.Handler, Assembly"
             resourceType="Unspecified" />

Handler
public class Handler: IHttpHandler, IRequiresSessionState
{

public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    var user = UserFactory.GetUser();

    if (user == null ||
        (!user.IsAuthenticated))
    {
        throw new HttpException(404, "Resource not found");
    }

    var filePath = context.Request.FilePath;
    context.Response.ContentType = "application/javascript";
    context.Response.WriteFile(filePath);
}

public bool IsReusable => false;
}


Your code won't compile - there's a stray opening bracket in the if statement. Otherwise, try using failed request tracing to see if that sheds any light on the problem.
